# Node Http Proxy - basic reverse proxy doesn't work (404s)

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to get a very simple proxy working with [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which I would expect to just return the contents of google:

```
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const targetUrl = 'http://www.google.co.uk';

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: targetUrl
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    proxy.web(req, res);

}).listen(6622);
```

For example I would expect http://localhost:6622/images/nav_logo242.png to proxy to http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo242.png instead of returning a 404 not found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `Host` header of your request

```
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const targetHost = 'www.google.co.uk';

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: 'http://' + targetHost
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res);

}).listen(6622);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    proxyReq.setHeader('Host', targetHost);
});
```

Inside an express app it's probably easier to use [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) when proxying some of the requests.

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
app.use('*', proxy('www.google.co.uk', {
  forwardPath: function(req, res) {
    return url.parse(req.originalUrl).path;
  }
}));
```

Comment: This does looks a lot easier thanks - I want https and possibly even websockets down the line though so I'll keep investigating

Comment: Note that in your example you sat up a local proxy. Connect to it and send `GET http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo242.png HTTP/1.0`, and it returns the correct file. So your setup was not right for a reverse proxy as you wanted to set up.

Comment: Yeah good point, I reduced it even more and it doesn't work. Posted an issue on their github to see if I can expedite an answer

Comment: GENIUS! I had tried the Host header but thoughtlessly had `http://` on it - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Set http-proxy option `changeOrigin` to `true` and it will set the `host` header in the requests automatically.

Vhosted sites rely on this `host` header to work correctly.

```
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: targetUrl,
    changeOrigin: true
});
```

---

As an alternative to express-http-proxy, you could try [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).
It has support for https and websockets.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use('*', proxy({
   target: 'http://www.google.co.uk',
   changeOrigin: true,
   ws: true
}));
```